# Построчное чтение информации из базы данных

Tags: c#, access, mdb

Написал данный код:

```
 private void ReadNextQuestion()
    {
          for (int i = 0; i < baseDataSet1.Tables["QuestionChoice"].Rows.Count; )
          {
                parseanswerquest = baseDataSet1.Tables["QuestionChoice"].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();
                tmp = parseanswerquest.Split(';');
                this.Text = baseDataSet1.Tables["QuestionChoice"].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                label1.Text = baseDataSet1.Tables["QuestionChoice"].Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();

                radioButton1.Text = tmp[0];
                radioButton2.Text = tmp[1];
                radioButton3.Text = tmp[2];
        }
    }
```

Собственно такой вопрос как мне отобразить на экране(именно смену значения label.Text и RadioButtons.Text которые берутся их бд) итерацию 0,1,2 и тд. по нажатию на кнопку?

Comment: Перепишите пожалуйста вопрос по-нормальному.

Comment: У вас в цикле нет приращения у `i`.

Comment: Убрал специально ибо после приращения получаю только последний i элемент.